# tableview background color is not correct, wrong color floats behind cell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

**What i have in code:** class inherited from UITableViewController  `myVC: UITableViewController`
have used xib i.e no dataSource and tableviewDelegates in .m, 
tableView is of kind Grouped and cell have white color 
i have set background in following way in viewDidLoad

```
 [self.tableView setBackgroundView:Nil];
    [self.tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"App_Background"]]];
```

also tried the backgroundView

```
 UIImageView *imgbg = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:self.tableView.frame];
    imgbg.image =  [UIImage imageNamed: @"App_Background"];
    [self.tableView setBackgroundView:imgbg];
```

**Problem:** left and right margin of cell have different color problem image inclosed

[image: background floation cell is red arrowed]
**for the blank table image is correct and this is how its required to be**

[image: blank table bg is correct] [image: required bg]**required bg of table is somewhat like this**also tried clearcolor for tableCell, even then blue floating cell bg is not changed

Thanks In Advance

Comment: why dont you try in xib file? take Uiimageview from objects put it in your viewcontroller xib and then on it put your tableview and then select background image in that uiimageview in xib this is how i do and it works for me

Comment: even in xib imageView with background image gives same issue

Comment: I must say its damn thing then :[

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UIView *background = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.tableView.frame];
background.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"App_Background.png"]];
self.tableView.backgroundView = background;
```

Hope it will help!

Comment: i appreciate your answer ,both imageView and View as you said as backgroundView for table gives blank background

Answer (score 1):

after trying all i removed XIb and made myVC to inherit from ViewController `:UIViewController` and created tableView programatically and set it backgroundColor as clearcolor and BGView Nil , setting the viewBackGround as the image i need , it worked

but i still wonder, why it dint worked using XIB or inheriting from UITableViewController